# How to setup VLC with gtk file dialog?

Tags: gtk, vlc, qt

My long lasting previous installation somehow tied up VLC and gtk file dialog. I didn't even do anything special, except installing VLC.

After update to VLC 2.2.1 the file dialog was replaced to Qt and I don't see any obvious way how to get back with gtk. When I mark "vlc-qt" for deinstallation, entire vlc is marked for removal as well.

openSUSE 13.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VLC media player has been using Qt interface for quite long time. VLC however, has an option to override window style, which will also change the file dialog as well.

In VLC media player, do the following steps:

1. Go to **Tools > Preferences** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. In the first tab, under **Interface Settings - Look and feel**, look for "Force window style:" with the drop-down menu and change selection from `System's default` to `GTK+`
3. Finally, click **Save** to apply the changes.

Then, go to **Media > Open File...** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to confirm that the file dialog has been applied with GTK+ window style. That's all.

Tested with VLC 2.2.1 in Debian 8 Xfce (Xfce 4.10).

### Force style for Qt5 in Debian/Ubuntu

Previously, for Debian 9 (testing) and Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) and older, user had to additionally install `libqt5libqgtk2` package from the repository. For newer releases, that is now provided by `qt5-gtk-platformtheme` or `qt5-gtk2-platformtheme` and either one will be installed automatically by recommends.

- Debian Testing (stretch) -- needed `libqt5libqgtk2`
- [Debian Old Stable (stretch) and newer](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=qt5-gtk)
- Ubuntu 15.10 (wily) until 16.04 (xenial) -- needed `libqt5libqgtk2`
- [Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and newer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt5-gtk&searchon=names)

Tested with VLC 2.2.2 in Xubuntu 16.04 (Xfce 4.12). I did not test in Debian, but reportedly works according to [this post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/700220). Later, I had observed that `qt5-gtk-platformtheme` package was installed by default for VLC 3.0.9 in Xubuntu 20.04.

### Force style for Qt5 in other distributions

The package above is not available in repositories of other distributions, including openSUSE, according to [this search result](https://software.opensuse.org/package/libqt5libqgtk2?search_term=qgtk) from software.opensuse.org. As an alternative, [this Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt) noted that `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` environment variable will force specific style to Qt applications.

Therefore, the line `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2` or `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=GTK+` may be added in one of the following locations:

- `~/.profile` (reportedly works in Linux Mint, suggested in [this post on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176696/125388))
- `~/.bashrc` (suggested in [this post on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/51166))
- `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` (suggested in [this post on FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/50957/#post-285899))
- `~/.xsessionrc` (suggested for OpenBox in [this post on CrunchBang Linux forum](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=438346#p438346))

Without installing the Qt5 package, I have tried export the line to each of above configuration files one at a time, except for the last one. However, none of these worked for VLC in Xubuntu 16.04.

At the moment, I can't verify whether the environment variable actually works or not.

Comment: Thank you, I already have such settings, but despite it VLC still uses Qt open dialog.

Comment: @greenoldman Updated my answer. I couldn't find what will actually work in other distributions to force style in Qt5 applications.

Comment: THANK YOU! Your last solution is setting the environment settings, so fast and dirty way to check it is to run `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=GTK+ vlc` and... it worked. So thank you very much for your help, I wish I could give you more points :-)

Comment: @greenoldman I tried again but failed to work in Xubuntu 16.04. I guess other distributions handle Qt5 differently from Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, man. I have installed libqt5libqgtk2 via Synaptic in Linux Mint Serena and after that the file open dialog in VLC looks really native. The  old one didn't even allow to open media files from hard drives that were not mounted yet (but plugged) and it wasn't quite intuitive.

Comment: Comment for rejected edit: [The answer by Maëlan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440809/125388) has mentioned that either `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` or `QT_QAP_PLATFORMTHEME` will work, so this earlier answer is still valid and the suggested edit does not make sense. Users who find the other variable worked for them should upvote the other answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to amend the accepted answer on how to get Qt to use the GTK+ theme (VLC now (2018) uses Qt5, so go by the second item).

- **Qt4** can use the current GTK2 theme. To activate this, simply choose `GTK+` as the style for Qt4 in its configuration file `~/.config/Trolltech.conf` (or using any graphical tool for configuring Qt4):

  ```
  [Qt]
  style=GTK+
  ```
- **Qt5** had support for GTK+ theming moved from the main package to a separate one. On ArchLinux, it is called `qt5-styleplugins`. Moreover, selecting the theme apparently goes by setting an environment variable, either `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` or `QT_QAP_PLATFORMTHEME` (both work for me), to `gtk2` (notice this is `gtk2`, not `GTK+`). Adding this setting to any of the script files listed by the accepted answer will do the trick. I would personally argue in favor of `~/.xinitrc` or similar, as this is related to the graphical environment.

  To sum up: on ArchLinux, install the package `qt5-styleplugins`, then launch your Qt5 application (VLC here) with `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=gtk2` set in the environment.

Links: [Arch Wiki on “Qt”](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Appearance), [Arch Wiki on “Uniform look for Qt and GTK applications”](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, things have changed, wrt the accepted answer "Force style for Qt5 in Debian/Ubuntu"

Initially I did not have a gtk option in the Force window style dropdown so tried to install libqt5libqgtk2 which reported:

```
Package libqt5libqgtk2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  qt5-gtk2-platformtheme
```

So install qt5-gtk2-platformtheme:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-gtk2-platformtheme
```

This gives you the gtk2 option in the Force window style dropdown. Select this and the VLC UI will change immediately. Tested the open file dialog too - looks much nicer

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a recent VLC version (with Qt5) in an GTK+ environment, you can install qt5-styleplugins, and then edit the Exec line in

```
/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
```

to

```
Exec=env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2 /usr/bin/vlc --started-from-file %U
```

This way you don't need to look for a missing option in VLC. Other suggested solutions didn't help for me.

If you also want that VLC to use the GTK open file dialog when starting vlc on the command line, add the following to `.bashrc`:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
```